# VB2010 - Delete Cells Not Containing Strings

Tags: vba, excel

I have made a "search" engine on VB2010 (**Windows Forms**) that checks a network drive for a specific excel workbook - depending on the input, it opens it and searches all worksheets and then copies certain cells to a new empty workbook.

My problem is that once the cells have been copied, there are some empty rows between the results. This happens because I have used the following conditions to delete a row. For example:

```
If wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").value <> "" Or wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").value <> " " Or IsNothing(wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").value) = False Then
       wb.Sheets(I).Range("C19").Copy()
       oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Pastespecial()
Else
       oBook.Sheets("Sheet1").range("A2").EntireRow.Delete()
End If
```

In my new workbook, the empty rows look empty but when you click on them they contain a formula shown on the top window, below the EXCEL toolbar.
The HasFormula command has been tried and does not work so i was wondering if you have a solution to my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just look to the property `FormulaLocal` of you cell !

Using someting like this in condition

`If wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").value <> "" Or wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").value <> " " Or IsNothing(wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").value or wb.Sheets(I).range("C19").formulaLocal <> "" ) = False Then`

If should countain the forumula that you are looking for